# Django modeltranslation too many fields

Tags: python, django, translation, admin, django-modeltranslation

I want to translate the `name` field in the django application (1.11) using django-modeltranslation. I want to translate to en and fr, but in the admin panel I get 3 fields instead of two: `name`, `name_en`, `name_fr`.

models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.SlugField(max_length=20, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name_en',)
```

translation.py

```
from events.models import Country

class CountryTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name',)
translator.register(Country, CountryTranslationOptions)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please inherit yout admin models from TranslationAdmin (instead of admin.ModelAdmin) as per

http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html

F. e you shoud have

```
from modeltranslation.admin import TranslationAdmin

class CountryAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
```